# Graphviz syntax shortcuts

Tags: graphviz, dot

Writing huge graphs in Graphviz is tedious. One day I will write my graphs in a custom format, which I will then transform into [DOT format](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language), but currently I want to find out the ways to write DOT files manually as succinctly as possible. I currently know of only [one syntax shortcut](http://graphs.grevian.org/example#example-7): `a -- {b c};` is equivalent to `a -- b; a -- c;`. In the DOT file currently there are many repeating patterns, for example many edges have the same label. Can I write something like:

```
// something that expands -m> into [label=meaning]
"English/cat" -m> "Meaning/cat_(Felidae)";
"English/cat" -m> "Meaning/domestic_cat";
"English/cat" -m> "Meaning/catfish";
"English/cat" -m> "Meaning/jazz_player";
"English/cat" -m> "Meaning/cat_(nautical)";
```

So that it would be equivalent to the below:

```
"English/cat" -> "Meaning/cat_(Felidae)" [label=meaning];
"English/cat" -> "Meaning/domestic_cat" [label=meaning];
"English/cat" -> "Meaning/catfish" [label=meaning];
"English/cat" -> "Meaning/jazz_player" [label=meaning];
"English/cat" -> "Meaning/cat_(nautical)" [label=meaning];
```

Is this possible? Are there any other possible syntax shortcuts in Graphviz that would make DOT files simpler and shorter? I would be happy if you could compile all such methods in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [dot language](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) allows default attributes for `graphs`, `nodes` and `edges`. These default attributes are valid for any new graph/node/edge defined after the default attributes, or until other default attributes are defined.

Your example could be rewritten this way:

```
// label for all edges from here on
edge [label=meaning];
"English/cat" -> "Meaning/cat_(Felidae)";
"English/cat" -> "Meaning/domestic_cat";
"English/cat" -> "Meaning/catfish";
"English/cat" -> "Meaning/jazz_player";
"English/cat" -> "Meaning/cat_(nautical)";

// no/empty label from here on
edge[label=""];
"English/cat" -> "Other";
```

The same applies for nodes and graphs, just use `graph [a=b, c=d, ...]` and `node [a=b, c=d, ...]`.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [marapet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28531994/596361), you can put default node/edge/graph attributes into a subgraph (see [DOT language documentation](http://graphviz.org/content/dot-language)), so the attribute changes will affect only the scope of the subgraph. Here, only edges `c -> d` and `e -> f` will have a label `"meaning"` attached, while edges `a -> b` and `g -> h` will have no label:

```
a -> b;
subgraph {
  edge[label="meaning"];
  c -> d;
  e -> f;
}
g -> h;
```